# E320 claims there is no OS

Tags: 11.10, installation, boot, thinkpad

I've just bought my shiny new Lenovo Edge E320, without an OS (though it was claimed to contain a DOS).

After now 4 re-installations of Ubuntu, I am desperate. When I pull the USB stick off and reboot, the laptop tries to boot from network. It does that, because it doesn't see the OS on the HDD. Every time it fails with the message "No operating system."

I've set the "boot" flag on all the partitions, checked the boot-order, set the HDD to top, re-parted and reset all the flags, re-installed Ubuntu, and I have no idea what else to try.

Please help me, I've saved up for an exciting new laptop and I can't use it.

Comment: This is a wild guess. Is the BIOS set to boot from the hard disk? When you run Ubuntu from the USB stick are there folders and files on the / partition?

Comment: I've even gone to the BIOS boot menu and tried to force a boot from Hard Disk, whereupon it just returned to it as there was no OS found. And I've checked the partition from the LiveUSB, it's all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set up a Gentoo. The laptop accepts GRUB1, but GRUB2 makes the problems. I am suspecting UEFI trouble.